# PhoneGap app not displaying correctly after download

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I have built an app using JQuery mobile. It works fine when I test it in a web browser. However once I download it to my phone using PhoneGap all the pages styles and layouts don't work. It is just a page of text. The app has two pages and some simple functions. I used Theme Roller for the styling, but nothing shows when downloaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Portfolio Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/MyTheme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="d">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="grid">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="grid">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>Personal Info</h1>

            <div data-role="collapsible">

                <h1>Past Work</h1>
                <p>Look at my past work</h1>

            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible">

                <h1>Education</h1>
                <p>Teaching myself to code</h1>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h2>My portfolio</h2>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="d">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page1" data-icon="grid">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2" data-icon="grid">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h1>Contact Me</h1>

            <form>

                <label for="essay">Tell me what you think</label>
                <textarea name="essay" id="essay" placeholder="Rate me"></textarea>
                <label for="range">Rate me out of 10</label>
                <input type="range" name="rate" id="rate" min="0" max="10" />
                <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Rate My App" />

            </form>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h2>My Portfolio</h2>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Provide the whole code for your HTML page including the header part. We need to see how you are linking the styles.

Comment: Thanks I have added the full code.

Comment: also set jQuery and JQM as local files

Answer (score 0):

After your theme, you should also add a reference to the JQM structure CSS:

```
    <!-- JQM theme shall be loaded before structure -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
```

After that, you don't need anymore the full `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css`.

... and also include jQuery and JQM as local PhoneGap files.

Comment: Thank you I understand now that I cannot reference the libraries like normal in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how PhoneGap apps work. They are not websites, so they don't behave like when you run them in your browser. PhoneGap apps run sandboxed in webview which shares a lot of features with web browsers, but has important differences. One important difference is security, which causes the issue that you're experiencing.

You are linking the jQuery libraries directly from the web. That will work when you run it in a browser which will download the files automatically. However, when you run the app on your phone, the webview will block those files, because for security reasons it blocks access to any external website. That's why you get your app with no styles or functionality.

If your app needs to access some website(s) like API (most apps do), then you have to tell the webview to allow access to those certain websites. You do than in your config.xml using the `<access origin="..." />` tag. However, we don't do that for the libraries, and we simply download them and bundle them with our PhoneGap app.

You downloaded (I assume from your code) the themes into a local folder in your PhoneGap project. That's good! However, you have to do the same for the next 3 library files. You have to download them into a local folder and changed the links accordingly.

Comment: Thank you that is a very clear explanation of what my problem is, I will try that.